# Swift - Can I use existing iOS keyboard to create custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I'm working on a custom keyboard, kind of like [Gboard](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2016/05/gboard-search-gifs-emojis-keyboard.html), but I didn't want to have to completely re-create the default iOS keyboard. Is there a way that I can just modify the existing keyboard? Or is there a package somewhere that has one available? I've exhausted all my resources I know of and caved and reached out to SO :). Let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. There are a few basic open source custom keyboards on GitHub that you might be able to repurpose, depending on their licensing and your needs.